# How to check which region more quick from my country

Tags: azure

I'm creating Azure web site. My country landed between Europe and Asia. Azure region option include 5 region (East Asia, West Europe, North europe, West US, East US).

How to choose which is quick from my country?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the routing to the Windows Azure datacenters. Have you tried testing the download speed, pings, ... to the Europe and Asia datacenters?

Try a tool like [wget](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/) or even Visual Studio. With Visual Studio (I think you'll need the Ultimate) you can create load tests which can perform different actions on your Web Site (like downloading files, loading pages, ...). Run this test on Web Sites deployed in different datacenters to get a better view about performance from your country (and you can use this information to choose where you want to deploy your Web Site).

Note that performance can still vary ISPs. If performance is key for your application consider using Cloud Services together with the Windows Azure Traffic Manager (configured with [performance load balancing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh744833.aspx#BKMK_PLB)). The Traffic Manager can redirect your user to the closest datacenter in terms of performance.